# Raspberry Pi Audio - Can not get 5.1 Surround Sound Audio to output to HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, raspbian-buster, omxplayer, pulseaudio

I have an applications where I need to do the following on a Raspberry Pi (3, 4, and/or Zero) running the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS:

Play an AC3 file with 5.1 audio over HDMI.
Play an MP3 or WAV file to a specific speaker in the 5.1 audio over HDMI.
I am currently using OMXPLAYER and have tried some of the Pulse Audio and APlayer approaches I found in other places but no luck so far. The problem is that I can not get the output to the HDMI port to be 5.1 as it keeps downmixinpg it to 2 channel audio.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Is the destination device 5.1 capable?  My old TV refused to take 5.1 in from the DVD player as it only had two speakers totally ignoring the amp etc connected via optical! This lead to standard stereo out till I connected the DVD to the Amp directly...

Comment: Yes, I have two different 5.1 receivers that accept HDMI.  I also have tried this with a Pi 3B+ and a Pi Zero W.